# Which cell size should I use in the LecoS plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, landscape

LecoS asks for the cellsize when calculating landscape statistics. However, there is no such information in the metadata of my input raster layer. Pixel size is 0.00126545,-0.00126497, but that can't be the required information? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The pixel size could be right if the coordinate systems uses degrees as units, like e.g. WGS84 does.